# Capture data during test execution

Tags: unit-test, test-automation

We have huge number of test classes and we are trying to automate capturing information about existing test classes. Data we are trying to capture is around governer limits (e.g. number of soql queries executed).
How can we do that? Is there a way to force test classes to write data to an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests leave no data behind, except for one: debug logs. You can access those logs in several different ways, such as the Developer Console or the Force.com IDE Test Runner. If you run tests from the Developer Console, they appear in the Tests tab, and from there, you can double-click on a test to bring up the Code Coverage summary, and from *there*, you can double-click on a method to see its logs. You can also access them directly from the Logs tab, but it's a little bit harder to associate a specific log with a unit test. There's a similar method in the Force.com IDE Test Runner to see those same logs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have 1000+ classes that changes regularly and we want to automate this process @sfdcfox .

Comment: @sfdcfox is it possible for us to send email of debug log once the test execution is completed?

Comment: @unidha It's possible to retrieve them via the API, but you'd have to write a script or something to do this. There's no default mechanism for getting the logs sent by email.